# Javascript Object Issue not able to send particular key

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i have a weird javascript issue.Here's my code I am not able to send these keys in my designOrder object. My Object does not have these fronImage and backImage keys that i am sending in my code.

```
let designOrder = await dbCall();

let allImages = []
allImageIds.push(designOrders.frontImageId);
allImageIds.push(designOrders.backImageId);

allImages = await dbCall();
let allImagesHash = {};
allImages.forEach(obj) => {
  obj.image = JSON.parse(image)
  allImagesHash[image.id] = image;
}

if(designOrder.backImageId){
  designOrder.backImage = allImagesHash[designOrder.backImageId]
}

// if i do console.log("1", designOrder.backImage) it will log the designOrder.backImage

if(designOrder.frontImageId){
  designOrder.frontImage = allImagesHash[designOrder.frontImageId]
}
// if i do console.log("2", designOrder.frontImage) it will log the designOrder.backImage

// but while console.log("3", designOrder) it will not show the backImage and frontImage keys 
return designOrder;
```

Comment: Can you check your code?   
Where does the image variable in `JSON.parse(image)` come from.  
Why do you have to call dbCall() twice, why don't you use designOrder instead of allImages

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: yes using mongoose and mysql both the first dbCall() is using mongoose the other one using mysql

Comment: Svetoslav Petrov the image is coming from the dbcall() of alImages. I am using dbcall twice because i am storing images in mysql and the id's are referred using mongo db

Answer (score 0):

It actually solved it after the first dbCall() i have added this line of code and it worked.

```
   designOrder = designOrder.toJSON();
```

toJson function is defined within the mongoose schema.